# Storing video clips for react/phonegap app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, phonegap

So I have an idea for an app that'll include numerous short video clips. 1st question, is it possible to publish a React/NodeJs/MongoDb application on the android app store using PhoneGap/Cordova? 2nd question, assuming that the first question is possible, how and where would I store/call these video clips for the app?

I've never developed on this scale, any and every tip is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on an application where i had to store small intro videos and pictures of a product, here is what i did and what you can do as well (of course you can choose other technology stacks)

What i did was use native Android Development(Java) for the android app and use PHP(Lumen) for backend where i store my videos on Cloud Storage on GCP.

You can build & publish your android app with PhoneGap(or Cordova choose which ever you are familiar with) and send the videos to your server for storage, your server can be built with NodeJS and MongoDB.

But if you haven't yet checked out Firebase i highly recommend it since it will remove many of the backend work(like uploading a video etc) and make development faster

Comment: Dope, thanks for replying! Could you please go a bit more into detail about how the videos will be stored and how I call upon them? At this point my basic understanding is that the videos will live on the web somewhere and when a user selects a video to watch the app calls the server that fetches the clip from the cloud or wherever the video is stored is that about correct?

Comment: yes you are correct! but if your video end up being 30mb or more, you should stream the video in chunks so you can have an interactive experience.
p.s accept answer if it helped lol

Comment: It'll be well over 30mb. I wouldn't be surprised if the number of clips exceeded a few hundred. So Firebase is good for videos?

Comment: yes it is. check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage but check if it supports what ever framework you choose for your mobile development